# Compare enumerable values that can't be sorted

Tags: scala, enumerable

I need to compare enumerable values, but the set of those values is not *[ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)*.

I have values `Rock,Paper,Scissors` and I want that `Rock` loses over `Paper` for example. This is not happening, see the last two lines of code

```
object Move extends Enumeration {
    type Move = Value
    val Rock, Paper, Scissors = Value
}
import Move._

object MoveOrdering extends Ordering[Move] {
    def compare(m1: Move, m2: Move) = {
        (m1, m2) match {
            case (Rock, Paper) => -1
            case (Rock, Scissors) => +1
            case (Paper, Rock) => +1
            case (Paper, Scissors) => -1
            case (Scissors, Paper) => +1
            case (Scissors, Rock) => -1
            case _ => 0
        }
    }
}

Rock > Scissors // evaluates to false, I'd expect true
Scissors < Rock // evaluates to false, I'd expect true
```

What am I missing that makes the code above *not* working as expected?

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 4):

I think you expect that `Rock > Scissors` would consider `MoveOrdering` instead.

Well thats now how it would work because `abstract class Value extends Ordered[Value]` with default implementation as:

```
 abstract class Value extends Ordered[Value] with Serializable {
    /** the id and bit location of this enumeration value */
    def id: Int
    /** a marker so we can tell whose values belong to whom come reflective-naming time */
    private[Enumeration] val outerEnum = thisenum

    override def compare(that: Value): Int =
      if (this.id < that.id) -1
      else if (this.id == that.id) 0
      else 1
```

So by default it uses the `index` of the element defined in the enum. In your case by default `Rock < Paper < Scissors`. If you wish to use custom ordering:

```
object Move extends Enumeration{
  type Move = Value
  val Paper, Scissors, Rock = Value
}
import Move._
implicit object MoveOrdering extends Ordering[Move] {
  def compare(m1: Move, m2: Move) = {
    (m1, m2) match {
      case (Rock, Paper) => -1
      case (Rock, Scissors) => +1
      case (Paper, Rock) => +1
      case (Paper, Scissors) => -1
      case (Scissors, Paper) => +1
      case (Scissors, Rock) => -1
      case _ => 0
    }
  }
}

implicit val o = implicitly[Ordering[Move]]

println(List(Rock, Scissors, Paper).sorted)
println(o.lt(Rock, Scissors))
```